# iframe is cut when in div on mobile safari

Tags: javascript, css, ios, html, mobile-safari

I would like to `scale` an iframe on `mobile safari`.

I am including an `iframe` inside a `div`.

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="iframe_container">
        <iframe src="http://jsfiddle.net/viebel/kTzDS/show" style="width:300px;height:300px;"/>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I am scaling the `div` with this code:

```
$(function() {
    $('#iframe_container').css({
        '-webkit-transform': 'scale(0.7)',
        '-webkit-transform-origin': '0 0 '
    });
});​
```

On **iOS**/Safari, the `iframe` is cut (i.e. can't be entirely seen) while on desktop/chrome, the `iframe` is *not* cut.

Here is a jsfiddle page with the code: http://jsfiddle.net/viebel/tJQUH/

Just to clarify: here is a demo page that demonstrates the real problem - when opened on iPad/iPhone Safari - all the three lines *should be* of the same size: http://jsfiddle.net/viebel/tJQUH/show

Please advice what can I do to see the `iframe` on Mobile Safari completely uncut?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have made few changes.Especially make the frame-size as 100%. Then try to scale the iframe itself.Check this out

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
              <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
              <title> - jsFiddle demo by viebel</title>

              <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js'></script>

              <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/normalize.css">
              <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">

              <style type='text/css'>

              </style>
              <script>
              $(document).ready(function()
              {
                //alert('hai');
                $('#ifd').css({
                    '-webkit-transform': 'scale(1.1)',
                    '-webkit-transform-origin': '0 0',
                    'width': '100%',
                    'height': '100%'
                });
              });

              </script>
            </head>
            <body>
                <div id="iframe_container" style="width:500px;height:400px;border:1px solid black;">
                    <iframe src="http://jsfiddle.net/viebel/kTzDS/show" id="ifd" />
                </div>
            </body>

            </html>
```

Link to jsfiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/viebel/tJQUH/13

Comment: Could you please fork my fiddle and make the changes you suggested and send link to the new one? It will be much easier to check. Thanks.

Comment: you just save and deploy the above page.Then check in the ipad.It is working

Comment: it works fine. But in my real scenario, the `iframe` is nested in a full hierarchy of `divs`. So I need a way to scale the whole hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

There's something wrong happening also on Safari Mac.

As a test, I would try to reload the iframe after changing the iframe_container CSS

```
var iframe = $('#iframe_container iframe');
iframe.attr('src', iframe.attr('src'));
```

Let me know if it's better!

Comment: Thanks! I will try later and let you know. If you have any other ideas, please share them.

Answer (score 0):

You are scaling the outer div not the iframe, try scaling the iframe and it might work.

And since you did specify that the iframe should be 300px, it would be easier just set the iframe height and width to 210px since that is 70 percent of 300.

Comment: Could you please fork my fiddle and make the changes you suggested and send link to the new one? It will be much easier to check. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use `jQuery's $(window).height()` to scale the iframe and also calculate the iframe dimensions on orientation change.