# How to apply css transform on iOS without using -webkit-transform?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios

On **iOS** (iPad/iPhone), I would like to apply some `css` transformation (rotate/scale) on html elements. I am experiencing some issues when using `-webkit-transform`. (See [iframe is cut when in div on mobile safari](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9484666/813665).)

I was wondering if there were another option to apply the transformations (maybe without Hardware acceleration) on **iOS** without using `-webkit-transform`.

Comment: Why are you **just** targeting safari? Do you not want anyone else to see your site? I think that is terrible design.

Comment: I am targeting iPhone and iPad. I assume that 99% there is Safari.

Comment: http://codepo8.github.com/prefix-the-web/

Comment: well, you may try 3d transforms )

Comment: @kirilloid Could you give me a pointer for material on 3d transforms?

Comment: http://www.webkit.org/blog/386/3d-transforms/

Comment: @kirilloid 3d transforms are applied via `-webkit-transform`. So it doesn't help.

Comment: @Andrew `prefix-the-web` doesn't help me. I want to apply the transform on **iOS** without `-webkit-transform`.

Comment: Yes, I know. But it is worth trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only real way to do those transforms is with the -webkit-transform tag. Alternatively, you can design the images / elements by hand and use .PNG files to maintain the transparency.